# Sublime add characters to the end of every line

Tags: sublimetext3

I have thousands of lines like this. If you look at the end of every line the insert statement is incomplete, it is missing ');.

```
insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31800400' , 24,    'CONTRATAÇÃO POR TEMPO DETERMINADO
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31809900' , 24,   'ELEMENTO GENÉRICO
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900101' , 24,   'PROVENTOS - PESSOAL CIVIL
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900106' , 24,   '13 SALARIO - PESSOAL CIVIL
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900118' , 24,   'LICENCA PREMIO PARA INATIVO CIVIL
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900121' , 24,   'PROVENTOS - PESSOAL MILITAR
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900123' , 24,   'AUXILIO-INVALIDEZ - PESSOAL MILITAR
```

I need to have this result

```
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900152' , 24,   'ADICIONAIS, VANTAGENS,GRATIFICAÇÕES E OUTROS COMPLEMENTOS DE PROVENTOS - PESSOAL MILITAR');
```

I cannot be like this, with trailing spaces at the end.

```
 insert into receita_siconfi (data_cadastro, codigo, exercicio_id, nome) values (now(),  '31900152' , 24,   'ADICIONAIS, VANTAGENS,GRATIFICAÇÕES E OUTROS COMPLEMENTOS DE PROVENTOS - PESSOAL MILITAR       ');
```

Does sublime Have a feature to cover this?